# How to rename/update columns name of entities in Jhipster ?

Tags: entity, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster and I would like to know how to rename the columns of entities in the database.
For example I have this on my .java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Usr implements Serializable {

...
    @Column(name = "id_env")
    private Integer idEnv;
...
```

I tried to change the name "id_env" and run the mvn liquibase:diff command but nothing happened on my database.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but an Entity Class is simply a "mirror" of your database table. If you want to rename a column of a database, open up your DB-explorer (whichever one you might use), and rename the column there, as well as in the entity. Again, I am not sure if I understood you fully :)

Comment: @Seth @ Gaël Marziou Thanks for your answers. I just wanted to change the name here :  @Column(name = "id_env") but not here : private Integer idEnv; I found a solution. I modified the name here and on the liquibase xml file and run the mvnw command. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `.jhipster/*.json` file of your entity and then re-run `yo jhipster --with-entities` to re-generate your code. Make sure your code is committed before running it and then merge.

Comment: If I run the command then the instance member name also gets changed.